# Fastcgi script "file not found" / Primary script unknown

Tags: nginx, debian, docker, openssl, fastcgi

**ACTUAL SITUATION**

I am in the process of transferring a static web server to a container.

**ISSUE ENCOUNTERED**

When i'm trying to reach my server, i received "File not found" with :

- curl command : curl --insecure -v -H "Host: <site_name>" https://127.0.0.1:443
- Browser : https://<site_name>

Here is the error message on NGINX container log for the site :

> 2023/07/04 13:25:38 [error] 8#8: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary
> script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client:
> x.x.x.x, server: site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://172.22.0.2:9000", host: "site"

Here is the 404 error on php container log :

> 172.22.0.3 -  04/Jul/2023:13:25:38 +0000 "GET /php/index.php" 404

**VERSIONS**

Here are my all versions used :

- OS Docker server : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6
- Docker : Docker version 24.0.2
- Docker compose : Docker Compose version v2.18.1

On containers :

- php-fpm : PHP 8.2.0 (fpm-fcgi) / Zend Engine v4.2.0 / Zend OPcache v8.2.0
- OS for php container : Debian 11.5
- nginx : nginx/1.23.1
- openssl : OpenSSL 1.1.1n
- OS for nginx container : Debian 11.5

**FILES CONFIG**

PHP-FPM container (i never modified the file, i removed the ";" lines for a better understanding) :

> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

include=/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
pid = /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
log_level = notice
daemonize = no
```

NGINX container :

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/site1.conf

```
     server {
             listen 80;
             return 301 https://<site_name>$request_uri; }
     
     server {
             listen 443 ssl;
             server_name <site_name>;
             root /webservers/site1;
     
             # Self-signed with openssl
             ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/testapp1/testapp1.crt;
             ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/testapp1/testapp1.key;
     
             location / {
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
             }
     
             location ~ \.php$ {
                     fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
                     fastcgi_index /webservers/oca/php/index.php;
                     #include        fastcgi_params;
                     #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/local/var/run/$fastcgi_script_name;
                     include fastcgi.conf;
             }
     
             location ~ \.(css|js|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png)(.*)$ {
                     expires max;
             }
         access_log /var/log/site1.info.access.log;
          error_log /var/log/site1.info.error.log; 
}
```

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    index php/index.php index.html index.htm;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;    
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

> /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;

fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;

fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;

fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;

fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;

fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;

fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;

fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;

fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;

fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;

fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

> ls -a /etc/nginx/

```
conf.d

fastcgi.conf

fastcgi.conf.bak

fastcgi_params

mime.types

modules

nginx.conf

scgi_params

ssl

uwsgi_params
```

> ls -a /webservers/site1

```
css

js

lifecycle_policy.sh

php

files
```

> ls -a /webservers/site1/php

index.php

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:0.1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command:
      - service nginx restart
    depends_on:
      - "php-fpm"
    links:
      - "php-fpm"
  
  php-fpm:
    image: php-fpm:0.1
    ports:
      - ":9000"
```

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO RESOLV IT**

I've trying many configuration which are indicated on forums but it didn't work.

> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

to

> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;

Restart NGINX

and another tests...

**WHAT WORKS**

It works without fastcgi_param :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
      fastcgi_index php/index.php;
}
```

But i have blank page...

It work with fastcgi_param :

Directly installed on VM with NGINX / OPENSSL / PHP-FPM (RedHat 8.7)

**QUESTION**

I know there is many answer on forums at this issue but i didn't find a good solution.
Have you suggestions ?

Comment: > /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 500
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
slowlog = /proc/self/fd/2
request_slowlog_timeout = 2s
catch_workers_output = yes
clear_env = no
security.limit_extensions = .php```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue :

I didn't understand that the .php file need to be in PHP-FPM container.
I build my own image of php-fpm and transfert the site files :

```
FROM repo/php-fpm AS builder
LABEL maintainer="x" description="NGINX PHP"
RUN mkdir /webservers
COPY --chown=root:root site1.tar /webservers
RUN cd /webservers \
    && tar xvf site1.tar \
    && chown -R root:root site1/* \
    && chmod -R 755 site1/*
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]
```

> docker image build -t php-fpm:0.1 .